# Display SKU for each Single product title in group product!

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Does anyone know how to display the SKU for each Single product title, underneath the Group product? I want to display the SKU to be obvious,as a second line,right below each product of the group.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try with the CODE below:

```
global $woocommerce , $product;
$sku = $product->get_sku();
echo $sku;
```

Comment: Hi Karan, welcome to WPSE. I've edited your answer with proper formatting. Please  [check this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to learn more about Markdown syntax used in StackExchange sites. Also, it's better for everyone if you also add some explanation with the CODE. Like where to put this CODE, which part of the problem does it solve and how etc. Hope to see you more in WPSE.

Answer (score 0):

I want to show the sku coe below from any title in grouped child products.

Where to put that code?
In functions.php?

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below in **functions.php**:

```
function wc_show_sku_grouped_product($value, $grouped_product_child){

global $product;

$sku = $product->get_sku();

if(!empty($sku)){

    $value .= "<div><strong>".__( 'SKU:', 'woocommerce' )." ".$sku."</strong></div>";

}

return $value;

}

add_filter('woocommerce_grouped_product_list_column_label', 'wc_show_sku_grouped_product', 10, 2);
```